# Gnuplot using shell command to set yrange

Tags: bash, shell, awk, gnuplot

I'm trying to set yrange in gnuplot by a variable which reads it value from a file.
The code i'm using is the following:

```
pres = "< cat log.xy | tail -n 100 | grep 'average(inlet) of p' | tail -1 |cut -d ' ' -f9 | awk '{print $1 - 5.0}'" 
pres_max = pres + 5.0
pres_min = pres - 5.0
set yrange [pres_min:pres_max]
```

Is there a way to pass the output of awk to a variable within gnuplot?
Or is there any other way the to set that yrange?

Comment: `cat`, `tail`, `cut`, `grep` and finally `awk`. That is exactly the synonym of `overkill`. Please bear in mind that you can almost everything with `awk` alone, what you can do with `cat`, `tail`, `cut`, `grep` combined.

Comment: Use gnuplot's own `stats` command

Comment: @tripleee This is not a duplicate question. In the link, the question is about how to use a command inside the plotting function. The solution which is proposed there, does not work for this question. 

Instead, here the question is about how to assign an output of a command to a *variable*, rather than using an output inside a plotting function.

Comment: Just to spell out the obvious, the entire pipeline can be refactored to `awk '/average\(inlet\) of p/ { p = $9 - 5.0 } END { print p }' log.xy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be possible that you are using the wrong quotes?

```
gnuplot> n = `echo 2`
gnuplot> print n
2
```

Applied to you specific case, and after some refactoring:

```
pres_max = `awk '/average\(inlet\) of p/{p=$9} END{print p}' log.xy`
pres_min = pres_max - 10
set yrange [pres_min:pres_max]
```

See section "Substitution and Command line macros" of the [gnuplot manual](http://www.gnuplot.info/docs_5.0/gnuplot.pdf)